# spectral norm of PSD matrices and inner product

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products, matrix-norms, spectral-norm

Is the operator norm on the space of $n \times n$ real PSD matrices derived from an inner product?
In particular, spectral norm for matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ defined as
\begin{equation}
\|  A  \| = \max_{x\in \mathbb{R}^{n}: \| x \|\leq 1} \| Ax \|_2,
\end{equation}
where $ \| . \|_2$ denote the $\ell_2$ norm in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$.

Comment: When $n>1$, no, because the norm doesn't satisfy the parallelogram law $2\|A\|^2+2\|B\|^2=\|A+B\|^2+\|A-B\|^2$. Consider $A=\operatorname{diag}(1,0)$ and $B=\operatorname{diag}(0,1)$ for instance.

Comment: By the way, the set of all PSD matrices is not a vector subspace of $M_n(\mathbb R)$. I suppose that you meant the subspace of all real symmetric matrices.

Comment: yep fixed thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comment by @user1551, I answer this question.

For the sake of contradiction assume that there exists an inner product $\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}\times \mathbb{R}^{n\times n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ over the vector space of all symmetric matrices in $\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$. Then, the [parallelogram law must hold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelogram_law). Therefore, if an inner product exists, we should be able to show that for every PSD $A$ and $B$, we have
\begin{equation}
2 \|A\|^2 + 2 \|B\|^2 = \|A+B\|^2 + \|A-B\|^2.
\end{equation}

Lets consider $A = \text{diag}([1,0])$ and $B = \text{diag}([0,1])$. Then, $ \|A\|=1$ , $ \|B\|=1$, $\| A+B\|=1$, and $\| A-B\|=1$. This example shows that parallelogram does not hold. Contradiction.

Comment: yeah fixed the typo.